# java AOP spring framework

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, aop

Is it possible to using Spring AOP advisor on a class that is not defined as a bean?

I would like to use a before- and after-advice on a class that is not defined as a bean in spring.xml file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. Spring can only apply advices on objects it manages.

Comment: ok thanks a lot Rohit Jain

Answer (score 2):

As Rohit Jain already stated correctly, objects advised by Spring AOP aspects need to be Spring components. But Spring also nicely plays with native AspectJ, as is described under [Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj). With AspectJ you do not have any such limitations and can easily advise simple POJOs.